# SOAP API V2 Response log

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, soap-api-v2

I'm trying to debugging SOAP API. I'm logging call Requests,
but how would I get log on Response?

I have tried to use [Magento-API-Logger](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/Magento-API-Logger) to get Response I've added

```
$logger->log($this->getResponse(), $logger::API_V2_SOAP);
```

to the V2/SoapController, but that gets response without body and it's not XML

```
DEBUG (7): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http Object
(
    [_body:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_exceptions:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_headers:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Content-Type
                    [value] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                    [replace] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => X-Frame-Options
                    [value] => SAMEORIGIN
                    [replace] => 1
                )

        )

    [_headersRaw:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_httpResponseCode:protected] => 200
    [_isRedirect:protected] => 
    [_renderExceptions:protected] => 
    [headersSentThrowsException] => 1
)
```

Any Suggestions how to get response log?

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/logger-for-soap-requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John suggested good thread which mention nice extension [N98_ApiLogger](https://github.com/netz98/N98_ApiLogger).
It logs API requests and responses. All logs are displayed in admin backend.

I found another way. by adding mage log to Soap.php.
I was looking for Wsi v2 so my file is
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Wsi/Adapter/Soap.php

around line 102 just after closing try block, add

```
Mage::log($content, null, 'response-api.log');
```

Thanks

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept your own answer.